# Where to download offline version of Tomcat docs?

Tags: tomcat

I want to download this:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is also available as a webapp on your filesystem which comes along with the Tomcat installation.

You can read the HTML docs directly from

```
<TOMCAT_HOME>\apache-tomcat-7.0.20\webapps\docs\index.html
```

Answer (score 3):

You can download the apache-tomcat-7.0.21-fulldocs.tar.gz file from http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi#7.0.21, under the "Full documentation" section.  This is a GZIP compressed file that contains the documentation.